# Issue with jQuery tabs and PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I'm working with PHP and jQuery tabs.
[image]

I am having an issue with the tabs. When I select a particular day in the above image it's taking me back to the default tab i.e. Profile. To check the selected date I have to click on bookings again.

I am using following script for tabs

```
    <script>
    $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    });
   </script>
   <br />
```

and for the first tab i have written "display:block" in style

Initially I want the first tab to be active. When I click on bookings tab I want to complete the actions i.e. selecting of date and other processes in that tab. Is there any chance I can keep the second tab in active state after selecting the date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the id of the bookings tab div onto the end of the link in the calendar that you are clicking preceded by a hash eg if your bookings tab div's id is 'tab-booking' you need to add `#tab-booking` onto the end of your hrefs.